# Mozilla extension publishing options

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, mozilla

I am working on the mozilla firefox extension and my requirement is that It should be private extension so only user who gets email with the link can download this extension. The Extension should not be visible to public. Second thing I want to know that is there any way to add firefox extension without leaving my company's existing application page? I want functionality like Google Chrome is providing "Inline installation" for adding the pluging without leaving the existing page..
If anyone has answers for these questions then please share... thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the info on distribution is here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Distribution

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is [better to include the essential parts of the answer here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.